# How to extract bridge name from brctl output with bash?

Tags: bash

i have a brctl output:

```
bridge name bridge id       STP enabled interfaces
testbr      8000.000000000000   no      
vlan.2      8000.b827eb33bfd5   no      eth0.2 
                                    veth689NIN
```

How can i parse this output to get only bridge name?

```
brctl show | awk 'NR>1 {print $1}' 
testbr
vlan.2
veth689NIN <-- wrong
```

Comment: Use NF>1 (number of **fields** in the row) like you are already using NR>1 ?
`'NR>1 && NF>1 {print $1}'`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe you could check also the number of fields (NF) like this:

```
brctl show | awk 'NF>1 && NR>1 {print $1}'
```

Answer (score 0):

Here  is a sed solution:

```
brctl show | sed -n '2,$ {s/ .*//; /./p}'
testbr
vlan.2
```

#### How it works

- '-n'

  This tells sed not to print anything unless we explicitly ask it to.
- `2,$ {...}`

  This tells sed to execute the commands in braces only on lines 2 and after.  This eliminates the header.
- `s/ .*//`

  This removes everything from the line after the first space.
- `/./p`

  If there is anything left on the line (meaning that it didn't start with a space), then print it.